# Change the color of text with a dynamic checkbox

Tags: javascript, checkbox

I'm working on a to do list. I can enter text within a field and create a new item with a checkbox, but I cannot get the checkbox to do anything. I would like to change the color of the text once the checkbox has been clicked

```js
function todoadd() {
    todoNew = new objectTodo();
}

function objectTodo() {
    var todo = document.getElementById('textinput').value;
    var listItem = document.createElement("li");
    var checkbox = document.createElement("input")
    checkbox.type = "checkbox";
    listItem.appendChild(checkbox);
    var itemText = document.createTextNode(todo);
    listItem.appendChild(itemText);
    document.getElementById('place').appendChild(listItem);
 
 function changeColor(checkbox,itemText) {
  var check = document.getElementById(checkbox);
  var todoItem = document.getElementById(itemText);
   if (check.checked == true) {
   todoItem.style.backgroundColor="Red";
   }
  }
}
```

```html
<title>ToDo</title>

<body>
<div id="container">
  <div id="todoList">
     <div id="textboxBackground">
    <input type='text' id='textinput' placeholder='What do you need to do today?' />
    <button type='button' id="myButton" class='button' onclick='todoadd()' value='Add to list' />Add To-do</button>
   </div>
   <ul id="place"></ul>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to bind event to all the checkboxes. Something like following-

```
var checkboxes = document.querySelector('checkbox');
for (var i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; i++) {
  checkboxes[i].change(function() {
    var text = this.parentNode.childNodes[]; // select the textnode here by giving the index to childNodes. Should be 0 or 1.
    if (this.checked == true) {
      text.style.backgroundColor="Red";
    }
    else {
      text.style.backgroundColor="grey"; // set the original color here
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: Is this part of a separate function?